# Need to change how to turn off caps lock in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

When I start Windows 10 on my laptop, my physical keyboard's caps lock can't be turned on; later it turns itself on and can't be turned off. At any time, if I start my on-screen keyboard (which I usually have off) I find its caps lock is on and I can't turn it off or quit the OSK. I can only fix these problems by restarting the PC; updating the physical keyboard's drivers and reinstalling it in the device manager didn't effect a permanent solution.

Based on [this](https://superuser.com/a/736601/512174) answer concerning this problem's occurrence in Windows 7, I should be able to fix this if I can find the to-turn-off-caps-lock setting. However, I can't find it in Windows 10 because keyboard language settings no longer include "advanced key settings". Can I do this directly in cmd or regedit?

Comment: First off, does the same issue persist with another keyboard or with the on screen keyboard (I assume not)

Comment: @Dave I wasn't able to type with my OSK; it crashed. I don't have access to another physical keyboard.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/disable-caps-lock-key/8083d4ee-721d-463f-aeda-630cd7f047c3 or https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/ (this second one states Windows 10 although I suspect the first may work) - Please note, I've not tried either so do it at your own risk

Comment: @Dave The OSK no longer crashes and can be used to change the key's state. The key started on; I deleted the regedit entry, after which at startup the key was on in the OSK but unilluminated on the PK. I'll keep experimenting and post an answer if I sort it.

Comment: @Dave The original version of the problem has returned: I don't think this fix will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caps lock can only be turned off by shift key, regardless of setting](https://superuser.com/questions/520559/caps-lock-can-only-be-turned-off-by-shift-key-regardless-of-setting)

Answer (score 0):

The setting you refer to in [this](https://superuser.com/a/736601/512174) post can be found this way in Windows 10:

- Windows Settings
- Region and Language settings
- Advanced keyboard settings
- Language bar options
- Select the "Advanced Key Settings" tab.

Answer (score 0):

press the start button or the windows key => type in "advanced keyboard settings" => pressing "Language Bar options" or "Input language hotkeys" opens up the same page => From here you may select to disable CapsLock by pressing the Shift key instead.